# Como quitar el foco del boton "Aceptar" en un MessageBox para que no se cierre al presionar Enter en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, messagebox

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que se usa un lector de codigo de barras para revisar los productos en un pedido como en el super mercado.

Cuando se supera la cantidad solicitada de producto se muestra un MessageBox con el mensaje "Excedente de producto" , el problema que tengo es que el lector de codigos funciona como si escribiera el codigo y al final presionara la tecla enter, por lo que si el usuario no esta atento , al leer otro codigo , la lectora automaticamente cierra el mensaje por que por defecto tiene el foco en el boton de aceptar.

Hay alguna forma de evitar esto, ya sea quitando el foco del boton aceptar, o de plano quitando el boton aceptar?

este es el codigo que intente ocupar , con la opcion de botones yes/no pero pasa lo mismo si presiona "no"

```
MessageBox.Show("Excedente de Producto", "ATENCION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio no se puede ya que las teclas estan asociadas a los botones por defecto, pero hay algunas alternativas que podrias evaluar

[MessageBox without a default button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612782/messagebox-without-a-default-button)

Podrias

- crear un MessageBox propio usando un form
- evaluar un tercer boton que definas por defecto l presionar enter

Si analizamos la documentacion

[Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxDefaultButton)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_MessageBox_Show_System_String_System_String_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxButtons_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxIcon_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxDefaultButton_)

hay una sobrecarga que permite definir un `MessageBoxDefaultButton`, o sea el boton que se accionara al presionar enter

Entonces si pones un tercer boton que evaluae en loop

```
DialogResult result;
do
{
    result = MessageBox.Show("Excedente de Producto", "ATENCION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3);
} while (result == DialogResult.Cancel);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
   //codigo
}
```

aunque siga leyendo con el lector de codigos los enters que este ingrese no cerraran el mensaje ya que el enter estara asociado a una tercera opcion

Comment: Perfecto, era justo lo que necesitaba , muchas gracias